# Javascript Error in IE 8- Site does not load

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, web

My site is http://www.ancientwords.us. I've tried every Javascript troubleshooting tool in the book, but I can't see to figure out why the site isn't loading in IE 8 (or IE7 for that matter).

When using IE10 in IE8 mode, I get a notification that there is a non-responding script, hence why I think it is a Javascript related error. Even still, I haven't been able to find a tool that has been able to tell me what's wrong.

I've tested the site in Safari, FireFox, and Chrome and everything works fine. The site also works fine in IE9 and IE10.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Cloudflare was causing the problem. The Rocket Loader feature is not compatible with older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [report the Rocket Loader bug](https://www.cloudflare.com/wco-bug-report.html) to us?

Comment: I did not. How can I do that?

Comment: The link was in his response :)